# Is a postgresql subquery in autocommit mode part of the same transaction or a different one?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency

I can't find anything explicit about this and I'm not sure whether "statement" in the documentation refers to an individual select or input text:

> By default (without BEGIN), PostgreSQL executes transactions in "autocommit" mode, that is, each statement is executed in its own transaction

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html

> Once acquired, a lock is normally held till end of transaction.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/explicit-locking.html

Specifically I'm locking a row in a subquery and then wanting that lock to be held when executing an outer update.  based on some fiddling it appears it's the same transaction so the lock should be held and there's no difference between putting it inside an explicit transaction or not, but I'm not entirely confident in my test:

```
=> select tx, txid_current() from some_table, (select txid_current() as tx, id from some_table limit 1 for update) dt where some_table.id=dt.id;
    tx     | txid_current
-----------+--------------
 218710796 |    218710796


=> select txid_current(), dt.*, pg_locks.* from some_table, (select txid_current() as tx, pg_locks.*, some_table.id from some_table, pg_locks where pid = pg_backend_pid() and     pg_locks.relation = (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') limit 1 for update of "some_table") dt, pg_locks where some_table.id=dt.id and pg_locks.pid     = pg_backend_pid() and pg_locks.relation = (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') for update of "some_table";
 txid_current |    tx     | locktype | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |         mode     | granted | fastpath |                  id                  | locktype | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid |     objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |     mode     | granted | fastpath
--------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+-------------    -+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+-------    ---+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------+---------+----------
    218709155 | 218709155 | relation |    16402 |   some_table |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 298/2506802        | 21958 |     RowShareLock | t       | t        | 5d229e5a-a1f3-11e6-96ea-0aaf4d035d37 | relation |    16402 |   (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') |          |       |            |               |         |       |          | 298/2506802        | 21958 | RowShareLock | t       | t
(1 row)

=> begin; select txid_current(), dt.*, pg_locks.* from some_table, (select txid_current() as tx, pg_locks.*, some_table.id from some_table, pg_locks where pid =     pg_backend_pid() and pg_locks.relation = (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') limit 1 for update of some_table) dt, pg_locks where     some_table.id=dt.id and pg_locks.pid = pg_backend_pid() and pg_locks.relation = (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') for update of some_table; commit;
BEGIN
 txid_current |    tx     | locktype | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |         mode     | granted | fastpath |                  id                  | locktype | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid |     objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |     mode     | granted | fastpath
--------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+-------------    -+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+-------    ---+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------+---------+----------
    218709152 | 218709152 | relation |    16402 |   some_table |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 298/2506801        | 21958 |     RowShareLock | t       | t        | 5d229e5a-a1f3-11e6-96ea-0aaf4d035d37 | relation |    16402 |   (select relfilenode from pg_class where relname='some_table') |          |       |            |               |         |       |          | 298/2506801        | 21958 | RowShareLock | t       | t
(1 row)

COMMIT
```

Comment: A subquery is part of the statement so it can't be outside the transaction. But I don't see any actual `UPDATE` in the statements you posted.

Comment: thanks for confirming that.  feel free to make it an answer and i'll confirm it.  i wanted to inspect the pg_locks and txid_current so i couldn't use an actual update but was trying to simulate its behavior with a select ... for update

Comment: A single statement is always atomic.